# ExtJS: Controller hide button after capturing event

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs5

I have three panels with three buttons each. When I press button '1' i want the other buttons '1' from each panel to hide. I'm a noob with ExtJS and i'm not sure how I'm supposed to program the Controller class. Please help.

This is the view class:

```
Ext.define('EventButtons.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
xtype: 'app-main',
viewModel: {
    type: 'main'
},

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},


items: [{
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    items:[{
        title: 'Buttons',

        items: [{
                title: 'Table1',
                id:'panel1',
                xtype:'panel',
                bodyPadding: 10,  
                width: 350,
                items:[{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '1',
                     id:'1',
                     name:'1',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     listeners: {
                        click: function () {

                                this.fireEvent('Name', this.text);
                                alert(this.name);
                   },
                        Name: function(name) {
                                if(this.text==name){

                                    this.hide();
                                 }
                        }}
                }]


            },
            {
                title: 'Table2',
                id:'panel2',
                xtype:'panel',
                bodyPadding: 10, 
                width: 350,
                items:[{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '1',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '2',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '3',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                }]


            },
            {
                title: 'Table3',
                id:'panel3',
                xtype:'panel',
                bodyPadding: 10, 
                width: 350,
                items:[{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '1',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '2',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '3',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                }]


            },

        ],


    }]
}],

});
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to do this, you need to add at least a cls for your buttons like button-1, button-2, button-3. Having an indicator for each buttons will help you get each of them by using Ext.ComponentQuery.

```
Ext.define('EventButtons.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
xtype: 'app-main',
viewModel: {
    type: 'main'
},

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},


items: [{
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    itemId: 'tab-panel-container',
    items:[{
        title: 'Buttons',

        items: [{
                title: 'Table1',
                id:'panel1',
                xtype:'panel',
                bodyPadding: 10,  
                width: 350,
                items:[{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '1',
                     id:'1',
                     name:'1',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     listeners: {
                        click: function () {

                                this.fireEvent('Name', this.text);
                                alert(this.name);
                   },
                        Name: function(name) {
                                if(this.text==name){

                                    this.hide();
                                 }
                        }}
                }]


            },
            {
                title: 'Table2',
                id:'panel2',
                xtype:'panel',
                bodyPadding: 10, 
                width: 350,
                items:[{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '1',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     cls: 'button-1'
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '2',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     cls: 'button-2'
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '3',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     cls: 'button-3'
                }]


            },
            {
                title: 'Table3',
                id:'panel3',
                xtype:'panel',
                bodyPadding: 10, 
                width: 350,
                items:[{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '1',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     cls: 'button-1'

                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '2',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     cls: 'button-2'
                },{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     text: '3',
                     width:80,
                     margin: '10 10 10 10',
                     cls: 'button-3'
                }]


            },

        ],


    }]
}],

});
```

In your controller, create a button click event and do the querying of other buttons here.

```
control: {

'#tab-panel-container button' : {
    click: function(buttonItSelf){
        var tabpanel = buttonItSelf.up('tabpanel'),
            buttonCls = "."+ buttonItSelf.getCls(),//assuming there's only one cls as of now
            otherButtons = tabpanel.query(buttonCls); // query all buttons with the same cls

            Ext.Array.each(otherButtons, function(key, button, arrayItSelf){
                if(button != buttonItSelf){
                    button.hide();
                }
            })
    }

}

}
```

I haven't tested my code this is just a rough idea of what you want to do.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will try it to see if it works. Thanks a lot!! Is there any possibility to just make the buttons to listen to an event that's fired in the whole app? And in the controller you would just have a method that fires the application wide event and another that listens to that event and hides the button that receives it.